# Regex for 0 or x - y characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write up a regex for a validation JavaScript, that allows the user to input 4-9 numbers (as the string length), but the user should also be able to leave the field blank.

The 4-9 numbers part is easy: `^[0-9]{4,9}$`, but I'm struggling on the "not required" part.

I've tried `^[0-9]{4,9}|[0-9]{0}$` but that doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply make your existing pattern optional:

```
^([0-9]{4,9})?$
```

Comment: *That* easy, huh? Thanks, tried it and it works! Will accept when possible :)